# Touch through GameObject, best practice

Tags: unity, touch

in the game I am doing atm you have an area with monsters.
There are two modes to damage monsters :

1. tapping on them
2. casting spells on the ground

Tapping and damaging a monster works fine.

The problem : If I have selected a spell and want to cast it on the ground, the monster collider blocks my touch of the ground behind the monster.

My solution was to disable the monster collider when I want to cast a spell.

```
    GameObject[] toDisable = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("Touch");

    foreach (GameObject g in toDisable) {
        g.GetComponent<Collider>().enabled = active;
    }
```

And ... it works.

Now my question is : Is this an adequate solution? They say GetComponent is slow, but I guess with 20 to 30 monsters running around it should be fine?
Anything else that could be done? Maybe there is some Unity magic I am not aware of.

Comment: You could store a reference to these colliders on start, or when you instantiate the monster. Then use them from there. Even if you do it this way, how many components does the monster have? Probably not more than 10. A linear search through 30 of them should be nothing, especially if this is only for one frame. I'd be more worried about the FindGameObjectsWithTag method.

Comment: You are right, I should cache those gameobjects somewhere... but It's not a difference if I do GetComponent<Collider>() or GetComponent<ScriptWithReferenceToCollider>() on the gameobject afaik...

Comment: No, cache the reference to the collider component itself.

Comment: I tried with the layermask and it works. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem : If I have selected a spell and want to cast it on the
>   ground, the monster collider blocks my touch of the ground behind the
>   monster.

No need to disable `colliders`. Just assign different layers to monsters, spells and ground. Then use the [collision matrix](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html) to specify that a spell doesn't collide with monsters.

(The same process, using `LayerMask` if you are using `RayCasting`)

> They say GetComponent is slow, but I guess with 20 to 30 monsters
>   running around it should be fine?

It's slow because there's no caching of `Components` in the Mono side of the scripts. Every `GetComponent` is forwarded to the native code which iterates through all components attached to a given `GameObject`. More objects, more calls. More components more thing to iterate through.

Definitely an overkill in this specific context.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. To clarify, I am using the IPointerClick interface, and both my monster and my ground implement it. I have a physics raycaster at my camera. Monster and ground are at different layers. Both monster and ground receive the clicks, but the ground obviously doesn't when a monster is there. The "skill" at this point is just a bool signaling I want to hit the ground, not the monster. So It's not about colliding gameobjects. The physics raycaster has an event mask, should I change this to floor only at keypress? Will this work? Sry for the inconvenience :)

Comment: I just had a quick test with the raycaster eventmask and it seems to work...

Comment: Sorry, I can't help with UI classes. I still didn't dig into them, so I have no idea how IPointerClick is supposed to work. In general, I think if that part of the engine is coherent with the rest (and probably this is the case), you should be able to filter raycasting using layers.

Comment: I tried with the layermask and it works. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have a solution:
Set the LayerMask of the PhysicsRaycaster accordingly.

```
public LayerMask normal; //Everything
public LayerMask attack; //Floor
public PhysicsRaycaster rayCaster;

void Update() {

    attackAllowed = Input.GetKey (KeyCode.Space);

    rayCaster.eventMask = attackAllowed?attack:normal;

}
```

Works like a charm.

Comment: glad you find a suitable solution for your specific needs :)